# Compute $|z|$ , $z = \frac{(2+i)^7(1-2i)^3}{(1+2i)^8}$

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

Compute $|z|$ , $z = \frac{(2+i)^7(1-2i)^3}{(1+2i)^8}$,

if $z = a+ib$ then,
I tried to do that with $|z| = (a+ib)(a-ib)$
then i multipled it $z$ with $z^-$ and then I got stuck. answer is $|z| = 5$

Comment: Use $$\left|\dfrac{ab}{cd}\right|=\dfrac{|a||b|}{|c||d|}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I still couldn't solve it. Can you please post an answer?

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complex_Modulus_of_Product_of_Complex_Numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
|z|^2=z\cdot \bar z=\frac{|2+i|^{14}|1-2i|^6}{|1+2i|^{16}}=\frac{(2^2+1^2)^7(1^2+2^2)^3}{(1^2+2^2)^8}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Olivier! Awesome hint. and you don't need the square root

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS No, I don't need to square it ;)

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: Use the following formulas: $||z_1z_2|| = ||z_1||||z_2||$, $||\frac{z_1}{z_2}|| = \dfrac{||z_1||}{||z_2||}$,and $||z^n|| = ||z||^n$. Can you continue?